# Applying margin and padding - bootstrap 5

Tags: css, bootstrap-5

I have begun trying to use bootstrap 5, and I am thoroughly lost. Below, is a layout I have created (i.e. the blue elements, the sidebar has been taken from this [source](https://dev.to/codeply/bootstrap-5-sidebar-examples-38pb)) and I am trying to replicate the following [layout](https://dribbble.com/shots/15725741-Sales-Dashboard/attachments/7527877?mode=media).

[image]

I am basically trying to add a neat margin between the blue elements and and making L1, L2, L5 and L6 the same height, and L3 and L4 half of that height, and center the blue elements in the white space.

From a [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/S23_P/vaLdfhzc/4/) I have did, the css3 code I have added for the individual styling of the blue elements is as follows:

```
.col{
    padding: 5rem;
    background-color: #33b5e5;
    border: 2px solid #fff456;
    border-radius: 10px;
    color: #fff;  
}
```

To reduce the size of elements, I have tried reducing the padding but the elements are positioned more towards the top of the page. Adding any margin causes the elements to overflow onto new lines.

Any help would be appreciated to get it close to the desired result. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

try to give margin to .col and remove `p-5` from col-10
[image: see the screenshot here]
.col {
padding: 1rem;
background-color: #33b5e5;
border: 2px solid #fff456;
border-radius: 10px;
color: #fff;
margin: 0.2rem;
}

[image: screenshot here]

Answer (score 0):

At a first look, don't use `padding` to play with the **height** of the elements, use `height` itself.

Also, don't apply css directly to the `col` class, it'll get harder to maintain. Use a different class name, and differentiate your `cols` based on them. Let's say L1, L2, L5 and L6 could be class `big-card`, and L3, L4 could be `small-card`. Apply a fixed height to these both. And remove all padding initially from the `col`.

```
.small-card {
    height: 200px;
}

.big-card {
    height: 400px;
}
```

Of course, adjust the height as per necessary. Then add padding according to the content that you put within the `cards`.

Then for the space between cards, use the `gap` class of bootstrap. Append this class along with `row`. Like: `row gap-3` will add a space of 16px between each card. (Of course, you'll need to have the padding of the cards removed first as I said, otherwise the layout will break because the width of the cards will be more than you are allowing).